# rendering with the video card in MeGUI

Tags: video, premiere, video-quality, encoding, compression

I do not know this is the right forum to ask for help.

**I need help to speed up rendering with the software MeGUI 2500.**

First I render to premiere with the help of CUDA.
*CUDA makes the video card also yield, speeding too.*

I put the second video has already ended in **MeGUI 2500 with AVS scriptcreator** decrease the size without affecting the quality too. Only in this software (MeGUI) did not find how to enable the video card to render.

*If you have no way someone could tell me other compression software that helps with the video card? Why premiere is not very good at it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you are trying to find a piece of software that can use hardware acceleration to encode video generated by AVISynth.  If that's the case, I'd suggest looking at Handbrake, which is capable of utilizing GPU acceleration and should handle AVISynth sources just fine.

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast. I will see this software.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to warn you that Handbrake here helped a lot, but for that you need to limit kbps between 2000 and 3000 (I'm studying the best kbps) and enable the "2-pass encoding" and "turbo first pass."

Also found Freemake. :)
This software enables CUDA and DXVA your video card to render, speeding lot in compression.